# How to copy few tables (not all) from dataset to another dataset in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider I am having dataset which contains 2000 tables and I want to copy only 1400 tables from them to another dataset within the same project. [Copying one by one](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) table will take ages to copy the whole dataset. however, if I copy the whole dataset (in TBs) at one go, it will incur charges of storing the whole dataset into another dataset. Are there any possible ways to copy only a few tables from a dataset at one go to another dataset within the same project (using wildcards, BQ command line, etc.)?

Comment: I had to do something similar recently, nowhere near your amount tables, but I saved a lot of time using the CLI to copy them. Could you consider copying the whole Dataset and then removing the tables you don't need? Might be less work.

Comment: I will consider your option if I don't get any workarounds. Thanks

Comment: I found a python script to automate this [here](https://blog.shaharia.com/copy-bigquery-dataset-to-another-dataset-copy-tables). But the problem with this is, it will start copying your data from the first table to "number of tables you specified". If we get something like from 10th table to 20th table then it would be great.

Comment: There is no python script in this link. Did you confuse it?

Comment: @AniketGhole, do you have all the table names you want to export ? Or do they have some sort of timestamp?

Comment: @rmesteves I wanted to write "found script" ..... can not edit it too...

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I have the names but they are date-sharded tables, for eg. events_(20) will have tables from events_2019-12-01 to events_2019-12-20

Comment: @AniketGhole, you can create a bq command to select the partition dates you want, save the list in a file and execute it with a bash command. Therefore, you would be able to copy all the tables to the desired destination data set or in the shell script make a list of all timestamps or tables and query then.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only worried about "it will incur charges of storing the whole dataset into another dataset" - don't worry too much about it:

1. Copy 2k tables via dataset copy.
2. Delete 400 tables ASAP afterwards.

The storage cost for those 400 tables will only reflect the time that it took to delete them - because:

> Storage pricing is prorated per MB, per second.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage